# MethodValidationPostProcessor breaks @Transactional

Tags: spring, transactions, bean-validation

I have a `Controller` which calls a `Service` which has `@Transactional` annotation.

But when I declare a bean `MethodValidationPostProcessor`, **no transaction is created** (could not initialize proxy - no Session).

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my"})
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Controller bean:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/my", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionalService transactionalService;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public void post(@SafeHtml @RequestBody String hey) {
        transactionalService.doStuff(hey);
    }
}
```

Service bean:

```
@Service
public class TransactionalService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void doStuff(String hey) {
        Item h = entityManager.find(Item.class, hey);
        h.getParent(); // could not initialize proxy - no Session
    }

}
```

I'd like to understand why `@Transactional` doesn't work when I declare `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.  Thanks !

Note: If I add @Transactional on my Controller, it works. But it's not what I want to do.

Comment: Without seeing your class that is hard to tell.

Comment: Hello, I've completed my classes as you required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Kakawait, I got a work-around: declaring my bean `MethodValidationPostProcessor`. Needs to be `static` so that @Transactional still work properly.

```
/**
 * This bean must be static, to be instantiated before the other MethodValidationPostProcessors.
 * Otherwise, some are not instantiated.
 */
@Bean
public static MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: I am hitting the same case and this solution works! But wondering is this on spring's bug list? spring boot 1.4.5

Comment: You saved me here.